# Error en la definición de rutas en aplicación React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

en proceso de aprender un poco React y en mi primera aproximación, estoy teniendo el primer inconveniente:

Este es mi archivo router.jsx

```
import {createBrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Authlayout from './layouts/Authlayout'
import Layout from './layouts/Layout'
import Inicio from './views/Inicio'
import Login from './views/Login'
import Registro from './views/Registro'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
      {
            path: '/',
            element: <Layout />,
            children:[
                  {
                        index:true,
                        element: <Inicio/>,
                  }
            ]
      },
      {
            path: 'auth',
            element: <Authlayout />,
            children: [
                  {
                        path: 'auth/login',
                        element: <Login />,
                  },
                  {
                        path: 'auth/registro',
                        element: <Registro />,
                  }
            ]
      }
])

export default router
```

este otro archivo es mi Login.jsx

```
export default function Login() {
  return (
    <div>Login</div>
  )
}
```

y por último, les muestro el archivo Registro.jsx

```
export default function Registro() {
  return (
    <div>Registro</div>
  )
}
```

ahora bien, si intento utilizar la ruta http://127.0.0.1:5173/auth, me devuelve correctamente el Authlayout, pero al convocar http://127.0.0.1:5173/auth/login, me tira el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no puedo resolver esta cuestión. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar? Desde ya, saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema se encuentra exactamente en cómo estás definiendo los  paths del children de tu ruta auth.
Como ya tienes definido tu ruta padre auth, ya no es necesario que vuelvas a repetir dicha ruta en las rutas hijas. Por lo tanto, tu router quedaría de esta forma:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
        path: '/',
        element: <Layout />,
        children:[
              {
                    index:true,
                    element: <Inicio/>,
              }
        ]
  },
  {
        path: 'auth',
        element: <Authlayout />,
        children: [
              {
                    path: 'login',
                    element: <Login />,
              },
              {
                    path: 'registro',
                    element: <Registro />,
              }
        ]
  }])
```

Puedes revisar más en la documentación de React Router Dom: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router